# HTTP прокси с авторизацией на C#

Tags: c#, http, авторизация, proxy

Всем привет. Подскажите, пожалуйста, несложный в реализации метод для создания своего локального прокси-сервера вида "localhost:port". Задача прокси состоит в том, чтобы перенаправлять все запросы на прокси с авторизацией вида "user:pass@host:port". И, соответственно, все полученные ответы отправлять назад. Копал Titanium proxy, но не разобрался, как с помощью неё авторизацию пройти. Возможно, есть ещё другие варианты?

Comment: Я так понял, вы хотите снифить трафик? Что вы будете делать с шифрованным трафиком, который сейчас практически везде используется?

Comment: Мне не нужно снифить трафик. Кто вообще так снифит?) Мне нужно перенаправлять его как есть с авторизацией на прокси, так как Selenium + Chrome этого не умеет делать здоровыми способами. Вопрос задан чётко, как есть. Не додумывайте и лучше не пишите, пожалуйста, если у вас нет ответа.

Comment: Чем вам [готовые](https://zen.yandex.ru/media/id/5ac5d5fb2f578c2060917c1f/sozdaem-svoi-sobstvennyi-proksi-server-na-windows-5aca3791ad0f22da2dae0139) прокси не угодили?

Comment: Таскать с собой левую прогу, да ещё и запускать несколько десятков её копий? Сами как думаете, хорошее ли это решение?

Comment: А насколько хорошее решение - собственная реализация HTTP Proxy? Я бы не решился, уж слишком много там всего, и зачем ее таскать? Если у вас проблемы с доступом к сети без прокси, я пойму, но не ходят же эти проблемы вслед за вами? На крайняк можно покопаться в NuGet пакетах, например [вот один](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Org.Mentalis.Proxy), или на гитхабе. Велосипедов уже очень много изобретено, зачем вам еще один?

Comment: А этот прокси может авторизовываться? Кстати, 3proxy по вашей ссылке выше авторизовываться не умеет, судя по документации.